# Is an entire function, with nowhere vanishing derivative, always a covering map?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables

Assume that $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is entire, and also that $f'(z)\ne 0$, for all $z\in\mathbb C$. Does that imply that $f$ is a covering map of $f[\mathbb C]$?

Clearly, $f$ is a local homeomorphism. Hence, the question reduces to examining whether such an $f$ has the curve lifting property.

Comment: I have seen this as an exercise.  I am not sure that it is appropriate for MO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surjective entire functions without critical points](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/147110/surjective-entire-functions-without-critical-points)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function $f(z)=\exp(\exp(z))$ gives a counterexample. The image of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, but the curve 
$$
\begin{align*}
\gamma:[0,1]&\to\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\},\\
t&\mapsto \exp(t),
\end{align*}
$$
does not have a lift $\tilde{\gamma}$ satisfying $\tilde{\gamma}(1)=0$ (the lift would have to be $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=\log(t)$, cannot be defined at $t=0$).

Answer (score 18):

**Answer.** *If $\,f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is an entire analytic function, which is a covering of $\,f[\mathbb C]$, then either $\,f(z)=az+b$, with $a\ne 0$ or $\,f(z)=\exp(az+b)+c$, with $a\ne 0$.*

*Proof.* We shall use the fact that if $\,f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is a covering, then it is a universal covering as well, since $\mathbb C$ is simply connected. Due to Picard's Little Theorem, there are only two possibilities:

a. $\,f[\mathbb C]= \mathbb C$. In such case, $g(z)=z$ is another universal covering, and the definition of the universal covering implies that $f$ is biholomorphic, and hence linear.

b. $\,f[\mathbb C]\ne \mathbb C$. Then $f[\mathbb C]= \mathbb C\!\smallsetminus\!\{c\}$, for some $c\in\mathbb C$, due to Picard's Little Theorem. Then $g(z)=\exp(z)+c\,$ is another universal covering of 
$\mathbb C\!\smallsetminus\!\{c\}$. 
Once again the definition of the universal covering implies the existence of a biholomorphic $\,h:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, such that $\,f=g\circ h$, and as $h$ has to be linear then
$$\,f(z)=g\big(h(z)\big)=\exp\big(h(z)\big)+c=\exp(az+b)+c.$$

Comment: In b) it might be good to mention that you're appealing to little Picard.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added it.

Answer (score 12):

An entire function cannot be a covering map, unless $f(z)=az+b$ with $a\neq 0$.
Indeed, the complex plane is simply connected, so every covering of the plane is
a bijection, and the ony entire functions that are bijections are polynomials of degree $1$.

According to Picard, the image of an non-constant entire function is either the plane or a plane with one puncture. In the case of one puncture, an entire function can be a covering over the image, and
this happens if and only if $f(z)=e^{az+b}+c,$ where $c$ is the puncture.

In general, let $f:S\to S$ be a holomorhic map between Riemann surfaces. Then either $f$ is a covering map, or it has a critical point or it has an asymptotic curve.

An asymptotic curve $\gamma:[0,1)\to S$ is such a curve that a) for every compact $K\in S$ there exists $t_0\in(0,1)$ such that $\gamma(t)\cap K=\emptyset$ for
$t\in (t_0,1)$ and b) There exists a limit $\lim f(\gamma(t))\in S$. This limit is called an asymptotic value.

EDIT. Example $f(z)=\int_0^z e^{-\zeta^2}d\zeta$ is surjective, so the image is $C$, and $f'(z)\neq 0$ but this
is not a covering: it has two asymptotic values.

Comment: The question asks about $f$ being a covering of its image, not of the whole plane; so $f(z)=\exp(z)$ is an example.

Comment: $f$ is a covering of $f[\mathbb C]$ and not of $\mathbb C$. For example, $f(z)=\exp(z)$ is a covering of $f[\mathbb C]$.

Comment: @Neil Strickland  and smyrlis: I edited the answer to address your remark.

Comment: I've got two off-topic questions about your "probability integral" function:

1) does $f(x)$ have exactly two asymptotic values?
2) is it true that there are paths ending in $\sqrt{\pi}$ that nevertheless lift (that is there are liftable paths that "approach $\sqrt{\pi}$ from another direction")?

Comment: @Dmitry K: the answer to both your questions is positive, if by "asymptotic value" you mean "finite asymptotic value". The function also has infinite asymptotic value, as every entire function does. To understand what is going on, it is instructive to draw the full preimage of the real line. This will break the plane into the regions which are mapped by $f$ $1-1$ onto the upper and lower half-planes.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Many thanks! Am I correct on the following qualitative picture: the full preimage of the real line is the union of some hyperbola-like curves (since the condition for $f(z)$ being real involves integrals, all i can say is that those are graphs of functions squeezed between $y=\pi k/2x$ and $y=\pi (k+1)/2x$  for various integer k). Each curve, except $y=0$, maps diffeomorphically on the real line (it need to be true to conform with your answer, but i dont know why, since that again involves  implicit functions and integrals which i couldn't estimate)

Comment: @Dmitry K: The picture is shown in Fig. 23, Chap. XI, sect 3 of Nevanlinna, Analytic functions. The curves are disjoint, each is a proper embedding of the real line, and they have 4 asymptotic directions, and they indeed look like hyperbolas. They break the plane into regions, one of them resembling a cross (bounded by 4 curves), and all others are like strips (bounded by two curves). One does not need to study any integrals to derive these geometric properties.

Answer (score 6):

To put the questions and answers in a wider context, the set of **singular values** $S(f)$ of an entire function $f$ is the set of points $w$ near which $f$ is not a covering map.

That is, $w$ is **regular** if there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $w$ such that $f\colon V\to U$ is a homeomorphism for every connected component $V$ of $f^{-1}(U)$, and **singular** if $w$ is not regular.
So $S(f)$ is the smallest closed set $S$ such that $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}f\colon \C\setminus f^{-1}(S)\to \C\setminus S$ is a covering map.

As discussed in the answers above, an entire function with $S(f)=\emptyset$ must be affine, and an entire function with $\# S(f)=1$ is an exponential map (by basic covering theory). In particular, no other function can be a covering over its range, by Picard's theorem.

On the other hand, the set of functions having two singular values is extremely rich.

(The above notions generalise immediately to functions between arbitrary Riemann surfaces. Of course here it is possible to have covering maps with larger numbers of omitted values.)