# Must a surjective infinitesmal isometry between simply connected spaces be injective?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, counterexamples

<strike>Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map between two simply connected Riemannian manifolds of the same dimension. It is also given that for every $x\in M$ we have that $Df|_x:T_xM\rightarrow T_{f(x)}N$ is an isometry of inner product spaces. Must $f:M\rightarrow N$ be injective ? I know the answer is yes if geodesic completness is assumed, but what happens if it is not assumed ?  Thank you.</strike>

---

**Edit:** The above version of my question was already answered in the comments thanks to Anton Petrunin. I am now interested in this slightly modified version of my previous question:

Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a **surjective** smooth map between two simply connected Riemannian manifolds of the same dimension. It is also given that for every $x\in M$ we have that $Df|_x:T_xM\rightarrow T_{f(x)}N$ is an isometry of inner product spaces. Must $f:M\rightarrow N$ be injective ? I know the answer is yes if geodesic completness is assumed, but what happens if it is not assumed ?  Thank you.

Comment: Let $N$=plane, $M'\subseteq N$ some annulus, and $M$=an open subset of a double cover of $M'$ which is simply connected and doesn't inject onto $M'$.

Comment: @Wojowu double cover of an annulus is not simply-connected.

Comment: Fixing problem in Wojowu's suggestion: Consider double cover of a tubular neighborhood of a projective plane embedded into a  euclidean space.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Thank you for your comments, I am sorry I still cant wrap my head around your example, can you please write it with more clarification as an answer?

Comment: Use Whitney theorem to embed $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^5$, the rest should be clear.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Ahh, I think I see. Sorry to bother you with more questions, but what would happen if I also required the map $f$ in my question to be surjective ?

Comment: It was asked numerous times at MSE. The answer is always negative.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you please give me the math exchange link , and I will delete this question

Comment: @AntonPetrunin That's why I am defining M to be an *open subset* of this double cover. Say you can remove one line segment from it. (that was for the original version of the question)

Comment: Here is an MSE question of the same nature: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553299/surjective-immersion-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-which-is-not-a-diffeomorphi/553408#553408

Comment: @MoshieKohan The link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147110/surjective-entire-functions-without-critical-points which you gave does answer my question provided I can also see that the functions of your link are not injective. I am trying to figure that out myself but maybe I am missing something

Comment: Yes, you are missing the simple fact that the only biholomorphic automorphisms of the complex plane are linear and the functions in the linked question are definitely not. You can also read my linked answer to the MSE question where lack of injectivity is immediate from the construction.

Answer (score 0):

Take three copies of the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. Call them $A$, $M$, and $B$, for "attic", "main floor", and "basement" respectively.

Cut slits in them as follows:

- small slits in $A$ and $M$ along the $y$ axis from $i$ to $i/2$
- small slit in $M$ and $B$ along the $y$ axis from $-i$ to $-i/2$.

Make stairs from the attic down to the main floor by gluing $A$ to $M$ along the open interval connecting $i$ and $i/2$: attach the right side of the slit in $A$ to the left side of the slit in $M$. Make stairs from the main floor down to the basement by gluing $M$ to $B$ along the open interval connecting $-i$ and $-i/2$: attach the right side of the slit in $M$ to the left side of the slit in $B$.

What results is a non geodesically complete Riemannian manifold that surjects onto the unit disk (another non-complete Riemanninan manifold) in an infinitesimal isometry that is not injective.